# PowerShell how to count all rows in html table in mail

Tags: html, css, powershell

This PowerShell code is creating a html table and send a mail with all users shown in the table, but how to add a counter. So I can see the total rows.

This is my code:

```
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$SubjectDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$EmailFrom = "test@test.com"
$EmailTo = "test@test.com"
$EmailSubject = "Test mail " + $SubjectDate
$SMTP = "smtp.mail.com"
$Head = Get-Content "C:\path\css.txt"
$Footer = "<br><br> This report is a test <br> Generated on $CurrentDate "
$Body = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=SOME,OU=DOMAIN" -Properties * | Where { $_.enabled -ne $false } | Select Name | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Head -PostContent $Footer -As Table | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -to $EmailFrom -from $EmailTo -subject $EmailSubject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $EmailServer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the User Count, like this:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=SOME,OU=DOMAIN" -Properties * | Where { $_.enabled -ne $false }
$Body =  $Users | Select Name | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Head -PostContent $Footer -As Table | Out-String
Write-Host "Total Users: $($Users.Count)"
Send-MailMessage -to $EmailFrom -from $EmailTo -subject $EmailSubject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $EmailServer
```

Comment: I tried to add the Write-Host "Total Users: $($Users.Count)", but the result was zero. PowerShell seems / pretends that it counts something, but it only shows: Total Users: 0

Comment: before sending email do `$users.count` do you get any results?

Comment: No it does not. It only gives the result directly in the console as shown in my last reply. Also Would like the results to be part of the mail. And not in  the PS console as it does now with Write-Host. I do appreciate the help.